# Is there a place that compares Halo CE and Anniversary glitches

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

Is there a site or someplace that has a list of glitches in Halo CE and compares them to ones that still exist in Halo CE Anniversary?

I've notice many still exist, like the 3 weapon glitch, and the ride the pelican, but I've also noticed some that were removed, like the getting on top of silent cartographer. Is there a nice list I can find somewhere that discusses what 'fixes' were made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still get on top of the Silent Cartographer, I've been up there you can move through the all the new scenery up there.  Halo Anniversary literally is Halo CE with new graphics thrown over it,  a vast majority of the code is exactly as it was in Halo CE.  I'd wager that all of glitches in Halo CE are still present in Halo Anniversary.

Comment: Driving to the middle of the island in a warthog, and trying to jump up onto the top is blocked by an invisible wall. I'll have to double check that at some point but I swear it was.

Comment: I stand corrected. You can indeed. I swear there was in invisible wall last time I tried lol